# numpy.argmax() not working on my sorted pandas.Series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Can someone please explain to my why the `argmax()` function does not work after using `sort_values()` on my pandas series?

Below is the example of my code. The indices in the output is based on the original DataFrame, and not on the sorted Series.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [4, 5, 3, 1, 2],
    'b': [20, 10, 40, 50, 30],
    'c': [25, 20, 5, 15, 10]
    })

def sec_largest(x):
    xsorted = x.sort_values(ascending=False)
    return xsorted.idxmax()

df.apply(sec_largest)
```

Then the output is

> ```
> a    1 
> b    3 
> c    0 
> dtype: int64
> ```

And when I checked the Series using `xsorted.iloc[0]` function, it gives me the maximum values in the series.

Can someone explain to me how this works? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the sort on the pandas Series, with which the indices also get passed along while sorting, and idxmax returns the *original index* with the highest value, not the index of the sorted series..

```
def sec_largest(x):
    xsorted = x.sort_values(ascending=False)
    return xsorted.values.argmax()
```

By using the values of `xsorted` we use the numpy dataframe, and not the underlying pandas datastructure and everything works as expected.

If you print `xsorted` in the function you can see that the indices also get sorted along:

> ```
> 1    5
> 0    4
> 2    3
> 4    2
> 3    1
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much. I am still having a hard time knowing the difference when to use the Series.values and when not to. Thanks.

Comment: You're welcome :). Pandas sometimes can be confusing, and this is one of those cases.